# Dirty memory use in iOS

Tags: iphone

My app uses about 50 MB of memory at startup when I look at dirty memory using the VM Tracker instrument.  It's a pretty simple app, and from what I recall at WWDC this year, this seems like way too much memory use for an app with only one simple UIWebview at startup.

I think I recall someone from Apple telling me to keep my memory use below 20MB as a guideline.

Before I go off and try to track this down - what's a good target to keep performance smooth and mem warnings reasonable?

Answer (score 3):

Virtual Memory != RSIZE. Don't get confused. Virtual Memory includes all sorts of shared memory, including mapped files and frameworks. What you really care about keeping low is your resident memory (RSIZE).

Comment: OK, thanks.  But the resident size is 155 MB, at the same time the dirty size is 48.39 MB.

Comment: I believe dirty size, in the far right column of the VM tracker is what matters, correct?  It indicates memory that can't be reclaimed (not a framework, etc). Frameworks, etc can be part of resident size, but not part of dirty size.  Right?